# Detect on which button need to change text in cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, tags, uitableview

I have like button in tableviewcell

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if ( !cell ) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];

        DBImageView *imageView = [[DBImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){ 0, 0, 320, 320 }];
        [imageView setPlaceHolder:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder"]];
        [imageView setTag:101];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
    }


    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [(DBImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:101] setImageWithPath:[tmpDict objectForKey:@"thumb_link"]];


    likeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] ;
    [likeButton setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width-60,280,81,33)];
    likeButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    likeButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 2, 0, 0);
    [likeButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:16]];
    [likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [likeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"heart_pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [cell addSubview:likeButton];


    // like button
    likeButton.selected = ![likeButton isSelected];
    NSInteger defaultKey2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:[tmpDict objectForKey:@"id"]];
    if (defaultKey2 == 0)
    {
        //[likeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:255/255.0 blue:255/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [likeButton setSelected:NO];
    }
    else if (defaultKey2 == 1)
    {
        //[likeButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:229/255.0 green:85/255.0 blue:140/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [likeButton setSelected:YES];
    }


    [likeButton setTitle:[tmpDict objectForKey:@"likes"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(like:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [likeButton setTag:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
```

This is my action:

```
-(void)like:(id) sender{
    UIButton *likebtn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSDictionary *tmpDict = myObject[likebtn.tag];
    NSInteger defaultKey2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:[tmpDict objectForKey:@"id"]];
    if (defaultKey2 == 0)
    {
        //Increase value
        int varTemp = [[tmpDict objectForKey:@"likes"] intValue]+1;
        NSString *strValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", varTemp];
        [likeButton setTitle:strValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefs setInteger:1 forKey:[tmpDict objectForKey:@"id"]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    }
    if (defaultKey2 == 1)
    {
        //Decrease value
        int varTemp = [[tmpDict objectForKey:@"likes"] intValue]-1;
        NSString *strValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", varTemp];
        [likeButton setTitle:strValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefs setInteger:0 forKey:[tmpDict objectForKey:@"id"]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];    
    }
    NSIndexPath *tmpIndexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:likebtn.tag inSection:0];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tmpIndexpath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
}
```

When I try to set title for my button in cell 
`[likeButton setTitle:strValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];` the value goes to wrong cell.

How can I detect for which button in cell value need to be set? How can I use my tag?

Comment: What do you mean "the value goes to wrong cell"? And could you please post your code from cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I need to increase or decrease my likes value, when i press like button, value changes in wrong cell.

Comment: OK, a couple things... In your `like:` method where's "likeButton" coming from within the conditionals? Because you declared "likebtn" at the start of the method. Two, you can't set the button title that way. It has to be set in cellForRowAtIndexPath. I'll post a suggestion soon once you explain where "likeButton" was declared.

Comment: I set my like button in cellForRowAtIndexPath and I set button title in cellForRowAtIndexPath from NSDictionary as well. But my problem is, that value comes from server and when I press button, value changes after few seconds and I want increase it faster, before it comes from server. In my .h file I set UIButton* likeButton;

Comment: I don't think you understood my question, but that's fine... I'll go ahead and write out my answer then explain from there...

Comment: I edited my question, hope it helps

Comment: Also there's a big problem now that I've seen your cellForRowAtIndexPath method. You've declared the button as a class variable?? (That was what my earlier question was about...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set the button title that way in your `like:` method, i.e.:

```
[likeButton setTitle:strValue forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

(1) Because you're reloading the table right afterwards thus manually triggering a call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and (2) even if you didn't reload the table data, even scrolling would trigger a call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and thus your cells would be populated based on `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`'s information.

As it stands now, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is using the following line to set the title:

```
[likeButton setTitle:[tmpDict objectForKey:@"likes"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

That means that in order for the `like:` action to trigger the title change, you have to change the [tmpDict objectForKey:@"likes"] value in `like:`. Since you're using a temporary dictionary and never add the dictionary back into the myObject array, you haven't changed the value that ultimately decides your button's title in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. So you have to update myObject accordingly. Here's my code suggestion:

```
-(void)like:(id)sender {

    UIButton *likebtn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = myObject[likebtn.tag];
    NSInteger defaultKey2 = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:[tmpDict objectForKey:@"id"]];

    if (defaultKey2 == 0)
    {
        //Increase value
        int varTemp = [[tmpDict objectForKey:@"likes"] intValue]+1;

        // Then update myObject
        [tmpDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", varTemp] forKey:@"likes"];
        [myObject replaceObjectAtIndex:likebtn.tag withObject:tmpDict];

        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefs setInteger:1 forKey:[tmpDict objectForKey:@"id"]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
    }
    if (defaultKey2 == 1)
    {
        //Decrease value
        int varTemp = [[tmpDict objectForKey:@"likes"] intValue]-1;

        // Then update myObject
        [tmpDict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", varTemp] forKey:@"likes"];
        [myObject replaceObjectAtIndex:likebtn.tag withObject:tmpDict];


        NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefs setInteger:0 forKey:[tmpDict objectForKey:@"id"]];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];    
    }

    NSIndexPath *tmpIndexpath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:likebtn.tag inSection:0];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tmpIndexpath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

}
```

Edit: Also there's a big problem now that I've seen your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. You've declared the button as a class variable? (1) Don't do that. Keep it local, ex:

```
UIButton *likeButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom] ;
```

(2) You're reusing your cells, but adding a new button each time. So you're adding one button on top of another on top of another with each `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` call. This could cause problems for you going forward.

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15768450'

Comment: @PavelKaljunen Hm... I'm not entirely sure why that is. But I've changed the code and broken up that line into two separate steps. Does it work now?

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSDictionary' declares the selector 'setObject:forKey:'

Comment: @PavelKaljunen Oh, tmpDict dictionary needs to be mutable. I'll change that too. And if myObject isn't mutable, you'll have to make that mutable elsewhere in your code...

Comment: Ok, same NSCFNumber length problem. NSLog(@"%@", [tmpDict objectForKey:@"likes"]); show number 100 and NSLog(@"%d", varTemp); show just a number. I don't know why your code doesn't work.

Comment: @PavelKaljunen Oh, is "likes" being stored as a string or a number? If it's being stored as a string then the call to cellForRowAtIndex path leads to an error because the title line is expecting a string, but I've set likes as an NSNumber. I'll change it to an NSString since I think that's how you've stored it in your dictionary...

Comment: I store it as NSString

Comment: @PavelKaljunen OK, great :)

Answer (score 0):

Your cell may reuse the buttons and tags can be disordered.
Try to refresh your bouttons' tags in tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method.

Comment: At the moment I have reuseIdentifier:nil